# Are part of great circles geodesics on spherically symmetric manifolds?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

While doing some study on geodesics on Riemannian manifolds, I learned that any geodesics on $n$-spheres are part of great circles. I then started wondering if that is true for any spherically symmetric manifold. My thought is, for a manifold $M=N \times  S^2$, since this manifold is spherically symmetric  I can always choose my coordinate system such that the polar angle is constant for the initial and ending points connected by the geodesic. But how can I prove that along the geodesic the polar angle doesn't change? I'm I wrong in my hypotheses?

Comment: Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258017/geodesics-on-the-product-of-manifolds?rq=1

Comment: @Neal Well, that settles it. Thank you for your comment, that post didn't pop up when I browsed for an answer. Thank you once again